# T-SQL If Statement issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, ado.net

I have 2 tables: `dbo.Videos` and `dbo.Checkouts`.
The `dbo.Videos` table contains a list of videos while the `dbo.Checkouts` table is keeping track of the videos that have been checked out.
The goal in my TSQL command is to insert a new row in the `dbo.Checkouts` table including `VideoId`, `UserId`, `CheckoutDate`.
Once this is successful I then want to update the `dbo.Videos` and decrement the `TotalCopies` column value based on the `VideoID` selected only if the value is greater than 0.
If less than 0 I want to throw an exception.
The `VideoID` in both tables are linked by foreign key.
However, the IF statement I have included in my statement below throws an error.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Checkouts (VideoId, UserId, CheckoutDate)
VALUES (32, 'b0281f0d-8398-4a27-ba92-828bfaa9f90e', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

IF (SELECT TotalCopies FROM dbo.Videos WHERE VideoId = 32) > 0
UPDATE dbo.Videos SET
TotalCopies = TotalCopies - 1
WHERE VideoID = 32
```

Comment: `below throws an error.` What error

Comment: Remove the `IF` and use `UPDATE dbo.Videos SET
TotalCopies = TotalCopies - 1
WHERE VideoID = 32 AND TotalCopies > 0`.

Comment: Shouldn't you check the `TotalCopies` value before inserting into `Checkouts` as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got it backwards.
Instead of adding a record to `Checkouts` and then test if you have the video in `Videos`, You need to first check you have a copy you can check out.
It's like when you go to buy something from any shop - first you get the product off the shelf, and only then you pay for it.
If the product isn't on the shelf, there's no need for you to pay.

### first version

You need at least three steps to do it right:
First, you check if you have a copy to check out.
If not, you don't do anything, just return a message that there are no free copies to checkout.
If there is a copy, you need to update the `Video` table (TotalCopies -= 1)
And last - you need to insert the record to `checkouts`.

The most important thing here is that if any of these steps fails, all of them fails - For instance, if for some reason you failed to insert the row to `checkouts`, you must revert the update you did on the `Video` table, since you can't complete the process.

This is the first reason why you need to wrap the entire process in a transaction.
The second reason you need a transaction is to avoid a race condition between the test if there are copies to checkout and the update of the `video` table.  You can read more about it on Dan Guzman's blog post about [Conditional INSERT/UPDATE Race Condition](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/28/Conditional-INSERTUPDATE-Race-Condition.aspx).

So, having said all that, let's show some code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE VideoCheckout
(
     @VideoId int, 
     @UserId uniqueIdentifier,
     @Success bit OUTPUT
)
AS

    SET XACT_ABORT ON 

    SET @Success = 0 

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY

        DECLARE @NumberOfCopies int
        SET @NumberOfCopies = ISNULL(
            (
                SELECT TotalCopies
                FROM dbo.Videos WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
                WHERE VideoId = @VideoId
            )
            , 0)

        IF @NumberOfCopies > 0
        BEGIN

            UPDATE dbo.Videos
            SET TotalCopies = TotalCopies - 1
            WHERE VideoId = @VideoId;

            INSERT INTO dbo.Checkouts (VideoId, UserId, CheckoutDate)
            VALUES (@VideoId, @UserId, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

            SET @Success = 1
        END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH

GO
```

### update - the using `@@rowcount` version:

SQL Server's [`@@Rowcount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql)  global variable returns the number of rows effected (generally. there are some exceptions that are documented in the link) - using that you can unify the test part with the update part - having SQL Server report back if the update effected any rows on not. This enables you to write simpler SQL and will probably have better performace.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE VideoCheckout
(
     @VideoId int, 
     @UserId uniqueIdentifier,
     @Success bit OUTPUT
)
AS

    SET XACT_ABORT ON 

    SET @Success = 0 

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY

        UPDATE dbo.Videos
        SET TotalCopies = TotalCopies - 1
        WHERE VideoId = @VideoId
        AND TotalCopies > 0;

        IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO dbo.Checkouts (VideoId, UserId, CheckoutDate)
            VALUES (@VideoId, @UserId, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

            SET @Success = 1

        END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH

GO
```

Comment: @mjwills Okay I understand. Yes, that might work, and it might be faster than both our answers.

Comment: As an analogy of why this approach is worth considering @Nisarg - let's imagine my wife asked me to go and buy some eggs. One option would be for her to ask me to go to the shops, see if there are eggs (`SELECT`) then if there are any ask the shopkeeper to put them to one side (the `LOCK` hints) and then go home. Then, I tell here there were eggs so she asks me to go get some (`UPDATE`). That **does work**. But it is **simpler** if she just asks me to go get some eggs if they are in stock (`UPDATE`) and let her know if I was successful (`@@ROWCOUNT`).